# cisco cuc installation

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, vmware

I've completed the installation of my CUCM 11.5 using a bootable .iso file.  Now I'm trying to install CUC for the voicemail and can't get it done because there isn't a bootable .iso only a regular .iso file.  I've followed the instructions at http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/connection/10x/install_upgrade/guide/10xcuciumgx/10xcuciumg010.html#81415 
 Where it says to edit the settings to first boot into bios and change the boot order to cdrom first, hd second and still vmware gets all the way down to network boot.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
http://htluo.blogspot.ca/2010/04/how-to-make-non-bootable-iso-image.html

> Make a non-bootable ISO image bootable For whatever reason, Cisco only
>   post "non-bootable" ISO images on CCO for download. In some urgent
>   situations, you might need a bootable disc to recover the system (or
>   your client/boss would shoot you in the head). Here's the procedure to
>   make a non-bootable ISO image bootable.
>
> Before you continue, be aware that this procedure is NOT approved by
>   Cisco. Neither Cisco nor I will be responsible for any loss caused by
>   this.
>
> Any bootable disc has to follow "El Torito" specification. No
>   exception for Cisco discs. The only difference between a bootable disc
>   and non-bootable disc is the "boot sector". Thus the solution is very
>   simple - extract the boot sector from a bootable disc and inject it
>   into a non-bootable disc.
>
> The boot sector is a very small file (usually less than 10k). And the
>   boot sector is usually content independent (i.e. you may extract the
>   boot sector from CUCM 7.1.3 and inject it into 7.1.5). You may save
>   the boot sector on your USB thumb drive and keep it handy.
>
> To extract/inject the boot sector, you need some disc image tools like
>   UltraISO. (You may also use other ISO tools with similar features)
>
> Step 1: Get the boot file
>
> There are two ways to get a boot file - extract from the DVD's file
>   system (regardless bootable or not) or extract from a bootable DVD's
>   boot sector.
>
> Option 1: Extract from DVD's file system (regardless bootable or not)
>
> This option is preferred as you don't have to find another bootable
>   disc or ISO file.
>
> The boot file should be available on any CUCM DVD, regardless bootable
>   or not.  It is located in the "isolinux" folder.  File name is
>   isolinux.bin.
>
> Extract and save the isolinux.bin file to your hard drive.  We'll need
>   to use that later.
>
> Option 2: Extract the boot sector from a bootable DVD
>
> If for some reason, you were not able to find/extract the isolinux.bin
>   file, you may extract the boot file from a bootable disc (or ISO
>   image).
>
> Put a bootable CUCM disc into the DVD drive and launch UltraISO. Go to
>   menu "Bootable > Extract Boot File from CD/DVD..."
>
> Save the file to your hard drive as a "boot info file" (bif). In our
>   example, we call it "boot.bif"
>
> Step 2: Inject the boot file
>
> Open the non-bootable image in UltraISO. Go to menu "Bootable". Make
>   sure "Generate Bootinfotable" was checked (it will NOT work without
>   this option). Then choose "Load Boot File...".
>
> Choose the boot file we saved before (isolinux.bin or boot.bif).
>
> Note that the image type changed to "Bootable".
>
> Now, you may go to "File > Save As" to save the bootable image to an
>   ISO file. Then you may burn the ISO to a disc with your favorite disc
>   burner software.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged because links go stale. Please edit your answer to include the relevant information, and include the link to give proper attribution.

Comment: Please give proper attribution where it is due. (I have edited the question to reference the source).